# Using Azure WebJobs or Azure Functions to host my console application which integrates with sharepoint online lists

Tags: azure, sharepoint, azure-functions, azure-webjobs

I am working on a sharepoint online team site collection. and i want to define a job which runs on daily basis to do the following:-

1. Integrate with SharePoint REST API, to get all the items inside a certain list which have their Due Date = Today.
2. send an email to a sharepoint group.

Now when i was working on such a task inside SharePoint on-premises, i use to follow this approach :-

1- I create a .net console app which integrate with SharePoint REST API, get the related items, and finally send the email using .NET `WebClient`, something as follow :-

```
//do the checks then send an email to the related group
    using (MailMessage myMailMessage = new MailMessage())
            {
                SPOutboundMailServiceInstance smtpServer = currentsite.WebApplication.OutboundMailServiceInstance;
                System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient(smtpServer.Server.Address);
                myMailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
                myMailMessage.Subject = subject;
                myMailMessage.Body = body;
                smtp.Send(myMailMessage);
                //code goes here..
            }
```

2- place the console application on the sharepoint server.

3- using windows task scheduler tool, i create a task which executes the console application on daily basis (@1:00 am for example).

**so now in sharepoint online i am not sure how i can host my console application + how i can schedule it ?**. i already converted all my code inside the console application to use the client-side module instead of server-side module. but my question is about hosting & scheduling the console application. i read about these options inside Azure mainly :-

1. WebJobs
2. Azure Functions

but i am not sure which appraoch is better to follow ? and which of the 2 tools mimic the appraoch of scheduling the console application using windows tasks scheduler?. now i read this article https://anthonychu.ca/post/azure-functions-scheduled-executables/ about Azure functions, but i got confused on what does `function.jso` file do? and not sure if i can run standard console application using these tools? also is there a UI to configure the trigger schedule as in the windows tasks scheduler case?
Thanks

Comment: I would use a function app with a timer trigger. I would recommend creating a function app in the Azure portal and seeing how far you get. It's pretty intuitive.

Comment: @JasonP can you explain why you will chose functions instead of webjobs?

Comment: Functions are the successor to webjobs. They have expanded functionality like more triggers and pay-per-run. I don't think there's really a reason to use a webjob for a new project.

Answer (score 1):

As Jason said, Functions are the successor to webjobs. Azure Functions is all about taking that core purpose of the WebJobs SDK, hosting it as a service, and making it easy to get started with other languages. We also introduce the "Serverless" concept here because it made a lot of sense to do so - we know how our SDK scales, so we can do intelligent things for you. While webjobs are backend console application which deploy in Web App.

> but i got confused on what does `function.json` file do?

The `function.json` file that contains the configuration metadata for the function. A function can only have a single trigger binding, and can have multiple input/output bindings. Below are examples for each of the trigger types. You could refer to this [wiki](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/function.json).

For deploying console app to Azure WebJobs, you could refer to this [article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2017/03/07/how-to-deploy-a-net-core-console-application-to-azure-webjob/) to zip your console app and upload it. To set [schedule trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-create-web-jobs#cron-expressions), you need to add a `settings.job` in you console app.

```
{
    "schedule": "0 */15 * * * *"
}
```

For deploy console app to Azure Function, you could refer to the [article](https://anthonychu.ca/post/azure-functions-scheduled-executables/) as you have provided with a timetrigger binding.

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "timerTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "schedule": "*/15 * * * * *",
      "runOnStartup": false
    }
  ]
}
```

So I recommend to use Azure Function to host.